# setting up squid proxy server

Tags: networking, server, proxy, squid

So, I need a IP address with a userneme/password combination to connect to my institute server to connect to the internet. But at one time I can use those credentials to log in from one single place only. So, I want to setup a proxy server in one of my laptop and use that server to channel all the network traffic from my other laptop/mobile to the main institute server. For windows sytem I ccproxy does the job, for ubuntu I am trying to use squid. So

1. From client device connect to the squid server, say the ip address 10.11.12.13:3128
2. squid collect the request and forward the traffic to the main institute server by using my actual log-in credential (IP (say 1.2.3.4:3128) and user/pass) .

Configureing squid,

I changed `http_access deny all` to `http_access allow all`. Then I added these line

```
cache_peer 1.2.3.4 parent 3128 0 no-query default login=username:password
never_direct allow all
```

But when Im trying to connect to the internet it says "Server not found". How do I setup squid to does the job.